# ExpandableListView with adapter

Tags: java, android

I want to create an ExpandableListView with custom adapter, however it only show my title group and when I click on the title (to view the children items) it doesnt do anything
(I want to have only one group item, therefore the item group count is 1).

Please help me to find where am I wrong, thanks alot.

This is my adapter:

```
class chatListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private String objectsIdInsideAdapter;
private List<String> commentsInsideAdapter = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> FacebookIdInsideAdapter=new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> NamesInsideAdapter =new ArrayList<String>();
private Context mContext;

chatListAdapter(String objectId,Context ctx,List<String> comments,List<String> face,List<String> names){
    objectsIdInsideAdapter=objectId;
    mContext=ctx;
    commentsInsideAdapter=comments;
    FacebookIdInsideAdapter=face;
    NamesInsideAdapter=names;
}
@Override
public Object getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return NamesInsideAdapter.get(arg1);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View v,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();


    if(v==null){
         v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_item, parent, false);
    }



    String comment =commentsInsideAdapter.get(position);
    Button sendCommentBtn =(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.chatitemSendComment);
        TextView commentView= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.chateitemViewComment);
        commentView.setText(comment);
        TextView commentName =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.chatitemfreindName);
        commentName.setText(NamesInsideAdapter.get(position));
        EditText commentText= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.chatitemEnterComment);
        commentText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sendCommentBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);




    return v;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return NamesInsideAdapter.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 1;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_item_group_layout,parent, false);
    }

    TextView groupName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.groupName);
    TextView groupDescr = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.groupDescr);

    groupName.setText("view comments");
    groupDescr.setText("groupDSCR");


    return v;

}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

and this is the code in the main Activity:

```
ExpandableListView  chat =(ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.ExpList); 

     String faceids =facebookIdChatInside.get(position);
     String comments = commentInside.get(position);
     String namesChat =nameChatInside.get(position);
     List<String> chatItems = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(comments.split(",")));
     List<String> facebookids = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(faceids.split(",")));
     List<String> namesList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(namesChat.split(",")));
     chatItems.add(" ");
     facebookids.add(id);
     namesList.add(name);


     chatListAdapter chatA =new chatListAdapter(objectsId.get(position),profileContext,chatItems,facebookids,namesList);
     chat.setAdapter(chatA);
```

I checked it, and those 3 Lists are not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your code i found 3 points that aren't so clear to me:

1. getGroup you return null? Why don't u return the real Object
2. getChildId you should return an unique id identifying your child
3. hasStableIds. You return false. You dont need to override this method.

If you want to  have more information on ExpandableListView give a look at my blog [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/01/android-expandablelistview-baseexpandablelistadapter.html)

You are using the ExpandableListView like a simple ListView why dont u consider to you a ListView?

Comment: hi , i dont want to use listView,also i look at this guide and getChildId and getGroup methods are return the save value as my code: http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html

Comment: Try to replace getInflater()  width LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService
                  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Comment: hi, still only show for me the group title "View comments, groupDSCR" and when i click on it, it doesnt open the list...please someone help me :)